# lubridate - messages

Tags: r, message, lubridate

Will it be possible to suppress messages such as "Using date format..." when using a function like?

```
> ymd(vec)
Using date format %Y%m%d
```

Whilst these are good to see when you are casting a vector, it can be annoying in some circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the `ymd` code, it callse `parse_date`, which gives those annoying messages via the command `message`.

Looking at `?message`, there is a corresponding `suppressMessages`:

```
suppressMessages(ymd(x))
```

(Note - other similar functions are `suppressWarnings`, `suppressPackageStartupMessages`, and `capture.output`, all of which I have had to use in the past to stop unexpected bits of text turning up (I was outputting some bits to an HTML file and these didn't want these to be in it)).

Comment: Yes I noticed that. What I was after is a function argument that has the same effect. The solution that you provided is rather inelegant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the only way - warnings have an option via `option(warn=-1)` but not messages.

Answer (score 0):

Manny, suppressMessages() is the only way to go at the moment. But I like your idea of an argument. I've put it on the todo list for lubridate. You could also use strptime() once you have the format for a vector of date-times.